# Collation Conflict can not solve in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

This is my query:

```
SELECT 
       CASE WHEN (
select Count(*) From (
select * from [mslccard08].[carekey].dbo.EXTERNAL_MEMBER_DATA 
union 
select * from [vmslcsql11].[HSRTest].dbo.External_Member_data) as t
) 
<> 
(
Select count(*) From [mslccard08].[carekey].dbo.EXTERNAL_MEMBER_DATA
)
THEN 'Data is not Identical'
ELSE 'Date is identical'
END AS RowCountResult
```

I am getting Following error

```
cannot resolve the collation conflict between sql_latin1_general_cp1_ci_as and sql_latin1_general_cp1_ci_ai
```

I know that error is because collation mismatch for one of the my column external Data with nvarchar type
I can solve the error by using `DefaultCollation`. As much as I understood DefaultCollation is used only with column_name. I am using * here. I don't know how to solve this error with scenario

Comment: Do not use *, but specify column list. `select * ... union select * ...` is quite nonsensical anyway - it will break, if any column definition changes or just column order between tables is not same, it will exclude duplicate results (bad, unless you specifically need that). You also could use just `(select count(*) from t1) + (select count(*) from t2)` - no problems with collation and structure then.

Comment: yes. but I have more than 20 Tables having 20 Columns each. Writing 400 times is quite time consuming. I am trying to find alternative if possible

Comment: Do you mean that you need to exclude duplicates? Otherwise you could use my second suggestion. BTW, writing 400 columns takes less time than arguing on stackoverflow :)

Comment: Haha. I am in search of general solution rather than arguing. :p I think stackoverflow is best for it, where you can find best solution rather than labour work

Comment: To compare records you can use `checksum()` function too (with properly collated column list of course). I can see no general solution without specifying column list; sure you can create some procedure to write dynamic SQL instead of typing/copying all column names manually.

Comment: @UbiquitousDevelopers please return and resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

Please find below the solution for your problem.
Change the table names with your tables.

```
declare @count as int
    set @count = 
       (Select Count(*) from 
       (select * from Broker
       union
       select * from Broker) as t)

SELECT 
       CASE WHEN 
       (
         @count <> (select count(*) from Broker)
        )
       THEN 'Data is not Identical'
       ELSE 'Date is identical'
       END AS RowCountResult
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. But When I try to union two tables it gives me this error. I think I will have same error with this solution also

Comment: Try this out because i have tried it and its working perfectly fine with me.

Comment: it works perfectly for you because all of your collations are the same

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT 
       CASE WHEN (
select Count(1) From (
select field1 COLLATE sql_latin1_general_cp1_ci_as  field1, field2 COLLATE sql_latin1_general_cp1_ci_as  field2 from [mslccard08].[carekey].dbo.EXTERNAL_MEMBER_DATA 
union 
select field1 COLLATE sql_latin1_general_cp1_ci_as  field1, field2 COLLATE sql_latin1_general_cp1_ci_as  field2 from [vmslcsql11].[HSRTest].dbo.External_Member_data
) t)
<> 
(
Select count(*) From [mslccard08].[carekey].dbo.EXTERNAL_MEMBER_DATA
)
THEN 'Data is not Identical'
ELSE 'Date is identical'
END AS RowCountResult
```

You need to correct the field names, it should work in union.
Changing collation with * does not seem to be possible.

**EDIT:Temp Table Option to change COLLATE when using * in select**

Create a temp table for first statement of the union then upsert records from second statement of the union and use this temp table for getting both table's count, refer code example below.

```
create table t1(name varchar(10) COLLATE French_CI_AS);
create table t2(name varchar(10) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS);

insert into t1 values ('`ffffn1');
insert into t2 values('general');

select * into #t from t1; -- First table of union
Insert into #t select * from t2; -- second table of union

select count(*) from #t; -- working
```

**------------------------------------------**
 So your query will change to;

```
select * into #EXTERNAL_MEMBER_DATA from [mslccard08].[carekey].dbo.EXTERNAL_MEMBER_DATA ; -- Create temp table having carekey records

Insert into #EXTERNAL_MEMBER_DATA select * from [vmslcsql11].[HSRTest].dbo.External_Member_data; -- add records from HSRTest

-- Use the temp table in query
SELECT CASE WHEN (select Count(1) From #EXTERNAL_MEMBER_DATA ) 
                    <> 
            (Select count(*) From [mslccard08].[carekey].dbo.EXTERNAL_MEMBER_DATA)
    THEN 'Data is not Identical'
    ELSE 'Date is identical'
    END AS RowCountResult
```

Comment: `select 1 from ... union select 1 from ...` returns single row, containing value `1` - this is certainly not correct result.

Comment: then change this to Union ALL or change Select 2 in second query

Comment: How would either of your changes allow compare results of two queries? From OP I did understand, that logic of queries is next: if count of distinct rows over first two queries is same as count of rows in third query, then first two queries return identical data. Maybe I have misunderstood requirements of course.

Comment: @Ubiquitous Developers you can refer the temp table option to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is related to using `select *`. Always avoid using this.

You were trying to union two columns with different collations. You wouldn't know which ones though because you were using `select *`

The statement below doesn't use `select *` at all and is likely to be much faster as it should work out the count on the remote server and return only three rows in total. Also it does not use `union` which is an expensive operation.

The important question is: **did you mean to use `union` instead of `union all` ?**

```
SELECT 
  RowCount1,
  RowCount2,
  CASE WHEN RowCount1 <> RowCount2 
  THEN 'Data is not Identical'
  ELSE 'Date is identical'
  END AS RowCountResult
FROM
(
  SELECT 
  (select Count(*) From mslccard08.[carekey].dbo.EXTERNAL_MEMBER_DATA)
  +
  (select Count(*) from [vmslcsql11].[HSRTest].dbo.External_Member_data)
  As RowCount1,
  (
  Select count(*) From [mslccard08].[carekey].dbo.EXTERNAL_MEMBER_DATA
  )
  As RowCount2
) As SubTable
```

Comment: Ok, I'll check it. Thank you for explanation and response

Comment: Looking at original posting, I would think that using `union`is required :(

Comment: Yes the logic is different but I'm assuming the OP doesn't know the difference, and since select * is being used there are unlikely to be duplicates anyway. If it is really required then using select 1 instead of select * will solve the problem.

Comment: And if there really are duplicates across the whole table (select *) then we need to know what the collations are so we can work out what to cast them to.

Comment: Sorry, but this query won't work. I want to check both table have exact data. that's why I used union. Union is mandatory I think

Comment: This query will check only count. I want to check data within table also

Comment: Your original query checks count only also. Functionally they are the same (except for union all). If you want to check the data is identical you need to indicate what the primary key is and indicate what the various collations are. What makes you think that query checks the table contents? It doesn't it just checks the count. Very slowly.

Comment: If you want to check table contents, use `checksum` as already suggested. Your existing query doesn't do this though. If you don't want to type out all the fields, you can right click on the table in SSMS and generate a select statement with all the fields in it and adapt that

Comment: In fact your use of `union` instead of `union all` excludes duplicates in the tables so you're definitely not comparing them.